# Counting the number of orbits of group action

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=A_5$ be acting on a set $A$ in such a way that no element of $A$ is fixed by every element of $G$. Suppose $|A|=10$. Prove that $G$ has at most two orbits in its action on $A$.

**My attempt**

I know that $G=A_5$ is simple, which might be useful since the kernel of any homomorphism mapping from $G$ must then be either trivial of all of $G$. And I guess I could approach by constructing a homomorphism. But I couldn't draw the connections.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a Burnside's lemma type deal. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orbit corresponds to a quotient of the group by a subgroup, and the size divides the order of the group. $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $30$ since that would be normal. Thus there are no orbits of size $2$. Since there is no element of order $15$, there is no subgroup of order $15$, so the orbits can't have size $4$. So only $3,5,6,10$ are possible. However, no orbit can be of size $3$ or $6$, for otherwise there would be a fixed point. Therefore there are either one orbit, or two orbits with $5$ elements.

Comment: Neat arguments! Thanks, Matt!

Comment: @mkmlp No problem.